# Inserting values from Vector to Map

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary

i got some issues trying to put the values of my vector in a new map (maMap)
If someone could explain me what contain my ItemIterator or how to do...

```
map<std::string,Employee*> Entreprise::convertiVectorMap() const
{
    map<std::string,Employee*> maMap;
    vector<Employee*>::const_iterator ItemIterator;
    for(ItemIterator = vector_employe.begin(); ItemIterator != vector_employe.end(); ItemIterator++)
    {
        maMap.insert(std::pair<string,Employee*>(ItemIterator->getNom(),ItemIterator));
    }

}
```

Comment: "I got some issues" What are they?

Comment: I don't know how to use my ItemIterator. i m supposed to insert a string value (from a getNom() method of Employee) as key and a Employee* as value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map is of `<std::string, Employee*>`, but you are trying to add an iterator as the second element of the `pair`. You need to dereference the iterator to get the `Employee` pointer.

```
maMap.insert(std::pair<string,Employee*>((*ItemIterator)->getNom(), *ItemIterator));
```

Or to save from dereferencing the same iterator twice, you could just use a range based `for` loop. As @CaptainObvlious mentions, you can also use `std::make_pair` to add to your `map`.

```
for(auto const employee: vector_employe)
{
    maMap.insert(std::make_pair(employee->getNom(), employee));
}
```

Comment: So ItemIterator is a pointer on my Employee pointer! i didn't know that. thanks!

Comment: @Nico not exactly, `ItemIterator` is an instance of class that imitates a pointer by providing overloaded `operator*` and `operator->`

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to derefrence your iterator:

```
maMap.insert(std::pair<string,Employee*>((*ItemIterator)->getNom(),*ItemIterator));
```

And since everyone asks for a *revamped* version of your code here we go:

```
map<std::string,Employee*> Entreprise::convertiVectorMap() const
{
    map<std::string,Employee*> maMap;
    for(vector<Employee*>::const_iterator ItemIterator = vector_employe.cbegin(), 
        ItemIteratorEnd = vector_employe.cend(); 
        ItmeIterator != ItemIteratorEnd; ++ItemIterator)
    {
        Employee* ptr = *ItemIterator;
        maMap.insert(std::make_pair(ptr->getNom(),ptr));
    }
}
```

You can also use ranged based for if you're at least in C++11.

Comment: `(*ItemIterator)->getNom();`, not `ItemIterator->getNom();`

Comment: Why not `std::make_pair` ?